# Unity 5 - Scene darkens when switching scenes

Tags: unity-game-engine, scene

Ok, here is a new issue.

I will attach 2 photos. (Note: this is a demo level)

The lighter image is the way the scene is supposed to look when it is loaded.  And in fact, it will load that way when I go to the scene and run it in the editor.

But if I load the level using Application.LoadLevel, it loads as the darkened image.  Even if I increase the intensity of the light, the level looks completely wrong.

This is happening for all my scenes, please help!

[image: The way the scene is supposed to be...]

[image: Darkened scene on Application.LoadLevel...]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Go to Window -> Lighting.
Click on Scene tab.
At the bottom uncheck 'Continuous Baking' and press Build.

This solved the problem for me when using Application.LoadLevel();

Comment: Thank you!  Just as an FYI, you need to remove the continuous baking PER SCENE.  So open the scene you want, uncheck the box and hit build.  All is fixed.  Thanks fuz.

Comment: Note - on Unity 5.6 inside Window -> Lighting you should uncheck "Auto Generate", then use the check box option to "Clear Baked Data" then after doing this you need to click "Generate Lighting" ( yes it is a button! )